# How to implement Fusioncharts Maps in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, charts, fusioncharts, angular-chart

Fusioncharts Maps hitting this error

> fusioncharts.js:19 GET http://localhost:8100/fusioncharts.usa.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

HTML

```
<fusioncharts width="100%" height="200" type="usa" dataFormat="json"
  [dataSource]="geographicDistributionDataSource">
</fusioncharts>
```

module.ts

```
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
// Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
import * as FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import * as FusionMaps from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.maps";
import * as Charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import * as Widgets from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets";
import * as Gantt from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.gantt";
import * as Powercharts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.powercharts";
import * as Msstackedcolumn2dsplinedy from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.msstackedcolumn2dsplinedy";
import * as FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";
import * as MultiCharts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.zoomline";

import { ModalModule } from './component/modal/modal.module';

// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, FusionMaps, FusionTheme, Charts, Gantt, Widgets,
  Powercharts, Msstackedcolumn2dsplinedy, MultiCharts);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    FusionChartsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FusionChartsModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import USA lib file in your module.ts

```
import * as USA from "fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.usa";
```

For other map definition files download this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fusionmaps